# Flask wheel file with static folder not being served

Tags: python, flask, waitress

I am trying to serve static files from flask app. It is working fine in development environment from visual studio code.

I made .whl file from the project including static folder.

In setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='techportal',
    #packages=['techportal'],
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'flask',
    ],
)
```

In MANIFEST.IN

```
include myportal/static/*
```

Then I installed wheel and created wheel file

```
pip install wheel
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Installed it using pip

pip install ./myportal-0.1.whl

In linux production server I run app using:

```
waitress-serve --port=8080 'myportal:app'
```

But I am not able to open url using:

```
http://192.168.0.1:8080/static/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **graft** for folders and include for files, i.e,

```
graft myportal/static
global-exclude *.pyc
```

"global-exclude *.pyc" just to exclude .pyc files, you can ignore that line in your MANIFEST.in file.